# Pre-planning data and S3 filenames for Athena Paritioning CSV by year, month, day

Tags: pandas, export-to-csv, amazon-athena

My goal is to have efficient Athena queries when the user wants to query for data within a specific day, but still allow for cross-day queries.

Sample file name to show the folder structure grouped by yyyy/mm/dd.

> https://xxx.s3.amazonaws.com/polygonData/history/csv/2020/11/02/polygonData_2020_11_02__12_00.csv

At this point, the month and date were all formatted to exactly two characters in the directory and file name.

However, I'm using Python's Pandas library to build the CSV from a Python Dictionary (JSON-ish), and in dictionary, the field doesn't have quotes around it, so the day of the month looks like this if it is one digit:

```
    "timestampYear": 2020,
    "timestampMonth": 10,
    "timestampDay": 2,
```

So in the CSV file, those three fields look like this:

```
2020,10,1
```

Here's a cut down version of my Athena schema.  Glue created the schema, but as I understand it, I have to substitute my partitioned field names since I didn't spell them out in the folder structure.

But I'm confused about strings vs double. I'm afraid that I will have to rebuild the CSV or rename the files at this point to get a query to work on the month and/or day.  Am I correct?

In other words, I can change the CSV's (1000s of them) to this format (should I use quotes or does it matter?)

```
2020,10,01 or 
'2020','10','01'
```

Or I could change S3 filenames to this: /02/ to /2/

> https://xxx.s3.amazonaws.com/polygonData/history/csv/2020/11/2/polygonData_2020_11_02__12_00.csv

This is a cut down version of my schema.  Glue generated one called csv, so I created another one called csv2 to fix the partitioning.

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE `csv2`(
  `ticker` string, 
  `timestamp` bigint, 
  `todayschange` double, 
  `todayschangeperc` double, 
  `createdbyuser` string, 
  `minuteopen` double, 
  `minuteclose` double
  )
PARTITIONED BY ( 
  `timestampyear` double, 
  `timestampmonth` double, 
  `timestampday` double)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED 
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat' 
OUTPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat'
LOCATION
  's3://xxx-athena/polygonData/history/csv'
TBLPROPERTIES (
  'CrawlerSchemaDeserializerVersion'='1.0', 
  'CrawlerSchemaSerializerVersion'='1.0', 
  'UPDATED_BY_CRAWLER'='AthenaPartitionedCSVQuoteData', 
  'areColumnsQuoted'='false', 
  'averageRecordSize'='3422', 
  'classification'='csv', 
  'columnsOrdered'='true', 
  'compressionType'='none', 
  'delimiter'=',', 
  'objectCount'='7662', 
  'recordCount'='16633692', 
  'sizeKey'='58735657820', 
  'skip.header.line.count'='1', 
  'transient_lastDdlTime'='1605289638', 
  'typeOfData'='file')
```

Query will be something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM "quotesdb"."csv2" 
where ticker = 'TQQQ'
and timestampYear = 2020 
and timestampMonth = 11
and timestampDay = 2
and timestampHour = 15
and timestampMinute between 20 and 25 
order by ticker, timestampisodatetime
```

Comment: I'm don't follow what it is that you are asking, could you make a summary and a clear ask at the end of your question perhaps?

Comment: Basically, can I make this work with integers, or do I need to change to strings.  What is "best practice" for this common scenario?